# How to order included elements in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have a model relationship where `today` has many `tasks`

I'm trying to retrieve a user's `today` object, include the `tasks` and render them all to Json. All of this was going great until I decided I wanted to order the `tasks` within the `today` object because `respond_with block` is also used for rendering the html page. Is there any way to include the `tasks` and order them?

I'm trying something like this:

```
class TodaysController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  def show
    @today = Today.where(:user_id => current_user.id).joins(:tasks).includes(:tasks).order(:priority).first
    respond_with @today, :include => :tasks
  end
end
```

This retrieves everything correctly, but does not seem to order the tasks at all.

This is what I used to have (which worked great, but didn't have the ordering):

```
class TodaysController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json
  def show
    @today = current_user.today
    respond_with @today, :include => :tasks
  end
end
```

I know I can retrieve the data and sort it afterwards like this:

```
@today = current_user.today
@today.tasks.sort!{|a,b| a.priority <=> b.priority }
```

This works and will pass my tests, but I was hoping for an ActiveRecord way to solve this.

Comment: Regarding your last line of code. The following is a bit clearer: `@today.tasks.sort_by(&:priority)`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this in your `Today` model:

```
has_many :tasks, :order => 'priority DESC'
```

EDIT: As mentioned in comment below, in Rails 4+, this is now:

```
has_many :tasks, -> { order(:priority => :desc) }
```

([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order))

Comment: Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: In rails 4 this is now deprecated, the new approach would be `has_many :tasks, -> { order(:priority => :desc) }` [read about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-model-with-order)

Answer (score 53):

Direct solution would be to include the `tasks` table name before `priority`:

```
Today.where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:tasks).order('tasks.priority').first
# joins(:tasks) is not required
```

Or, if you don't want to have the table name hardcoded, you can merge with scope from `Task` model:

```
Today.where(:user_id => current_user.id).joins(:tasks).includes(:tasks).merge(Task.order(:priority)).first
# joins(:tasks) here is required
```

Also, you can add `has_many: todays` to `User` model to ditch the `where` clause and do:

```
current_user.todays.includes(:tasks).order('tasks.priority').first
# or
current_user.todays.joins(:tasks).includes(:tasks).merge(Task.order(:priority)).first
```

But if you need only/always to order by priority, and do not need other different orderings, adding `order` to `has_many :tasks` is easier.

Comment: I don't see why adding the order to the model is better. It seems to me that ordering is part of the view, and has nothing to do with either model.

Comment: True. I meant easier. Edited.

Comment: @Jack `Today.where(:user_id => current_user.id).joins(:tasks).includes(:tasks).merge(Task.order(:priority)).first` its not working on rails 4.2

Comment: Should work, don't have 4.2 to test it now, for sure works in 5.
Anyway, since 4.0 you should actually use `references` with `includes` to indicate you will use the table in the query.  So it should be something like `Today.where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:tasks).references(:tasks).merge(Task.o‌​rder(:priority)).fir‌​st`