# Organize lecture with chapter and lesson models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am trying to organize my models so that I get to see in lecture.rb > chapter.rb > lesson.rb. As you can imagine chapter.rb have to be organized by order in the view as well as the nested lesson within chapters.

It is a bit confusing.. My idea so far was to create those models.

```
class Lecture
has_many :lessons, through: :chapters
has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter
# lecture_id / name / should I use an integer to order it ? 
has_many :lessons 
belongs_to :lecture
end

class Lesson 
# I added a :step which is an integer in order to order them?
belongs_to :lecture
belongs_to :chapter
end
```

Is there a better way of doing that ? The main purpose is to well organize the lectures.

Comment: how is this related to activeadmin?

Comment: I'm using active admin to create all the lectures. Basically I should be able to create everything chapter and lessons directly from the active admin panel using nested forms

Comment: and what's the question? how to organize associations or what?

Comment: Question is about my models. Should I use an integer in order to organise the chapters and the lessons

Comment: How would you do that otherwise ?

Comment: If you need to know, which chapter is 1, which is 8 and so on - absolutely, use integer for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want a lambda scope block. Try this:

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters, -> { order(number: :asc) }
  has_many :lessons, through: :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lecture
  has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :lecture, through: :chapter
end
```

got it from [Deprecated warning for Rails 4 has_many with order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order)

This would work with a integer column 'number' in the chapters table. You could do the same with Lessons if they have an order.