# rails - get all elements order by an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, haml

I would like to display a list of phases from a project. For that I load all phases in the controller

```
def load_project
    @project = Project.find params[:id]
    @phases = @project.phases
end
```

Then I go through @phases using the each function in the haml

```
- @phases.each do |phase|
    %tr ...
```

The problem is that the sql request from previous code doesn't have any order attribute, so it's the default order by id.

```
SELECT `phases`.* FROM `phases` WHERE `phases`.`project_id` = 123
```

I would like to order this request by a phases attribute call "position". Is it possible to add an order option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project.rb

```
has_many :phrases, order: 'phrases.column_name'
```

So this will order all phrases of your project with column_name you specified

You can do this if you want by default association should be ordered

Comment: I didn't knew you can add order to the model, thanx :) Just a note, order looks to be deprecated in rails 4, should use scope block instead : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18284635/3703099

Answer (score 1):

You can add [order](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) in controller, or in view

```
def load_project
    @project = Project.find params[:id]
    @phases = @project.phases.order(:position)
end
```

Or

```
- @phases.order(:position).each do |phase|
    %tr ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax, but I'll use @test model's edit so I don't need to think about adding order everytime :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@phases = @project.phases.order("position ASC")
```

rather add scope to the model phases like this

```
scope :ordered, order: "position ASC"
```

and call this way

```
@phases = @project.phases.ordered
```