# Rails: Ordering comments in a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want my comments to show at descending order, but adding *:order* in Post model doesn't work.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, :order => "created_at DESC"
    validates :title, presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 50 }
    validates :body, presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 20, maximum: 200 }
end
```

I get an argument error on show action of *PostsController*. What's the method used to do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order

Comment: @vee I get this error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: position: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  ORDER BY position desc` I tried all methods from answer.

Comment: Ooops, I had to change _position_ with _created_at_. It works now, thanks.

Comment: what rails version you use?

Comment: @Ilya I'm using 4.2.6