# ArgumentError: Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error while running rake db:migrate:

> ArgumentError: Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name,
>   :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name,
>   :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend,
>   :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type,
>   :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type

This is the model where I am getting error:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :icons, :order => 'position_id ASC' #showing error here..
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

Please help.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
has_many :icons, -> { order('position_id ASC') }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order).

`has_many :icons, -> { order('position_id ASC') } #showing error here..`