# Rails 5: Ordering child objects in parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models:

- `state_records, has_many :weight_categories`,
- `weight_categories, has_many :lifts`,
- `state_records, has_many :lifts, through: :weight_categories`

The form for `@state_record` includes both the creation of `weight_categories` and `lifts` via the cocoon gem. Each `@weight_category` has 3 lifts but these lifts need to be in a specific order.

When I create the form everything is OK. When I update the form (only in production), occasionally the order of the lifts will change. I don't have anything in the code to define the order because I assumed it would order itself by created_at. Everything works fine in development but not in production. I assume it has something to do with having postgres as my production database and sqlite3 as my dev database.

I think I need to just define the order but don't know the best way to do this. Everything gets displayed through the State Record's model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284606/deprecated-warning-for-rails-4-has-many-with-order/18284635#18284635

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov any suggestions on how to go about making sure the lifts are in the correct order when updated?

Comment: ActiveRecord does not change `created_at` when updating records. So, if you sort records by `created_at` and are **updating** records, then you shouldn't observe any changes in order. So, if you still see the changes, then some of these assumptions are wrong or you are doing something differently.